# Which book to read together with Royden's Real Analysis?

Tags: reference-request, book-recommendation

Which book should one read together with *Real Analysis* by H. L. Royden and P. M. fitzpatrick, 4th edition, so that the former book (i) elaborates and clarifies the details omitted in the proofs in the latter,  and (ii) contains solutions to some, most, or all of the exercise problems in the latter?

Are there any course webpages --- featuring lecture notes, problem  sets with solutions, and video lectures --- for any undergrad-level courses based on Royden?

Comment: I haven't read it, but Axler's book [Measure, Integration, and Real Analysis](https://measure.axler.net/) looks good. Axler's book Linear Algebra Done Right is very popular.

Comment: For the second requirement, you need a solutions manual.

Comment: Measure, Integration & Real Analysis does not have a solutions manual, but the book was written to be more student-friendly than Royden's book. Also, the electronic version of Measure, Integration & Real Analysis is legally available for free at https://measure.axler.net/.

Comment: @SheldonAxler Thank you very much for your very user-friendly book.

Comment: [Here](https://www.amazon.com/Solutions-Manual-Analysis-Royden-Fitzpatrick/dp/B0B147SJ7R/ref=tmm_hrd_swatch_0?_encoding=UTF8&qid=&sr=) is a book with some solutions.